# Convert ImageMagic convert script to Ghostscript script

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I have an ImageMagick command for converting first page of a PDF to an image.

```
convert file.pdf[0] -background white -flatten -resize 173 \
     -crop 173X229+0+0 -gravity NorthWest +repage test.jpg
```

Here I needed 173px width image with max 229px height for the first page.
For bigger files (~9MBs), convert was taking around 2 mins.

When I tried to test it with gs using the following, the script took only a fraction of seconds:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o test4.jpg file.pdf
```

I need help resizing the image to 173px and then cropping the height to 229px. Can anyone help with this gs script?

Comment: Read the Ghostscript documentation :-) You will need the -dFIXEDMEDIA switch as well as -gXandY to set the desired page size (in pixels) then you will finally need -dPDFFitPage to scale the page into those dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @KenS. I am able to get a bit of it working by using your hints above - ` gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -g173x229  -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage  -o test6.jpg file.pdf `
However there one more issue - I am getting a rotated image when Im using a landscape oriented pdf. i.e the image is rotated as a potrait. I cant seem to find anything useful for this. Can you help?
I tried adding params - -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice"  but this throws an error

Comment: If it fits better when rotated, the the FitPage routines will rotate it, because it involves less downscaling. If you want to avoid that, you'll need to rewrite that code. They are written in PostScript, how are you at coding in PostScript ? Altering the Orientation in the media matching won't help, because you have specified the media size with -g

Comment: I have never coded in PostScript, but I would like to learn it. I need to know if its not a big task , then I will go deep and do it. If there are some examples for reference , that would be of great help.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like the work is done in the routine pdf_PDF2PS_matrix which is defined in /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps. It does have some minimal comments in there so you may be able to work out what's going on.

Comment: Tried to read the code but everything seems out of context to me. :( 
Also, since convert (Imagemagic) uses ghostscript, I tried to debug it - it uses this command  `gs -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -sDEVICE=pam -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72x72 -dUseCIEColor -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-x5Soig16-%08d -f/tmp/magick-oUtVPcyF -f/tmp/magick-KM8ZEc5d`
Does this make sense since its using -dGridFitTT=2 and not -dPDFFitPage. Overall, when I tried to run , it takes a lot of time.

Comment: GridFitTT is to do with TrueType fonts, nothing to do with pages (it also has no use these days, its ignored). -dUseCIEColor will make the colour come out badly and very slowly, this switch should only be used if you are running a carefully colour managed workflow. Its not scaling the output at all, so I suspect ImageMagick is scaling the bitmap after rendering. The poor choice of controls, along with the post-processing, will be why its slow. No, I can't rewrite the Page fitting code for you, not least because you have not supplied an example! Can't work in the dark....

Comment: The sample pdf I am trying is here - http://selector.com/media/documents/active-for-a-new-eco-active-architecture-3.pdf  The command I am trying is - `gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -g173x229 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -o test6.jpg file.pdf ` as mentioned above, the image gets rotated. Also , in portrait mode instead of scaling to 173X229 I want it to just scale to width and crop the height to 229. How can I do that? Thanks for helping me out here @KenS

Comment: Made an answer because I can highlight code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps at around line 2086 is the routine pdf_PDF2PS_matrix which does the scaling. At around line 2094 we see:

```
currentpagedevice /.HWMargins get aload pop
currentpagedevice /PageSize get aload pop
% Adjust PageSize and .HWMargins for the page portrait/landscape orientation
2 copy gt   % PageSize_is_landscape
7 index aload pop 3 -1 roll sub 3 1 roll exch sub exch
10 index /Rotate pget not { 0 } if cvi 90 idiv 1 and 0 ne { exch } if
gt  % Box_is_landscape
ne {
  1 index 0 translate 90 rotate % add in a rotation
```

This checks the orientation of the media which has been set against the orientation of the requested media from the PDF file, and if they are not the same, it rotates the PDF file by 90 degrees.

You can change this to:

```
currentpagedevice /.HWMargins get aload pop
currentpagedevice /PageSize get aload pop
% Adjust PageSize and .HWMargins for the page portrait/landscape orientation
2 copy gt   % PageSize_is_landscape
7 index aload pop 3 -1 roll sub 3 1 roll exch sub exch
10 index /Rotate pget not { 0 } if cvi 90 idiv 1 and 0 ne { exch } if
gt  % Box_is_landscape
ne pop false {
  1 index 0 translate 90 rotate % add in a rotation
```

which will prevent the if clause from executing (by pop'ping the boolean from the stack and replacing it with a 'false') so the rotation will not take place.

For me this does not rotate your landscape pages.

How you use this depends on how your Ghostscript has been built, which may depend on the package maintainer for your Linux distribution.

If the resources are built into a ROM file system, then you will need to locate the copy stored on disk, modify the file, and then either rebuild Ghostscript so that the modified file is built into the ROM file system, or use the -I switch to tell Ghostscript to ignore the ROM file system and read the resources form a location on disk.

If Ghostscript is not built to use a ROM file system then you need to locate the resources on disk, and modify that file. Or again you can use the -I switch to tell Ghostscript to use a set of modified resources.

It may be best overall to use the -I switch anyway, as that way you can retain the normal resources, and only use this modified code when you want to do this task.

Comment: Thanks. Worked absolutely fine. I see that a lot of whitespace is left in both landscape and portrait styled pictures. Anything we can do about it?

Comment: You can do all sorts of things. As I recall the white space is in the original document, but it uses a CropBox to have Acrobat display without it. Either make the document without the white space in the first place, or set -dUseCropbox. Landscape pages are *always* going to have white space if you render them to a fixed portrait medium.